USB Keyboard non responsive on old HP ProDesk when installing Linux Mint or Proxmox.. Something common here
Details:
HP ProDesk 600 G1 SFF running on an Intel core i5 4590.
AMI BIOS L01 V02.65 dated 7/13/15.
Booting ISO image from DVD.
(USB thumb drive install will not work regardless of BIOS config)
USB Keyboard does not respond during initial install menu selection. Tried many BIOS configs. And key/keyboard combinations.
Linux Mint installer starts a countdown timer without keyboard
entry and defaults to "Install Linux Mint".
After successful boot, the keyboard and mouse do respond.
My original intent was to install Proxmox and test VMs on a Cisco VLAN switch. Unfortunately Proxmox does not countdown to default and no guarantee that the next menu selection will work. In the mean time, I'm trying to find a PS2 keyboard and mouse. In reading many similar questions on various sites, there may be something to do with IOMMU. If so, I can't find where in the ISO I can edit IOMMU=soft and such.
I'm just cutting my teeth on Linux and Grub so please respond with specific folder/file locations and names.
Additional details: The HP ProDesk was a refurb with Win10 Pro installed.

IOMMU=soft isn't applicable if you have Intel CPUs.

What would be common between Linux Mint 22 and Proxmox 8.2 that would cause the installer to fail to read the keyboard. Is this a function of Grub?

Nothing relevant here. If it doesn't work in UEFI ("BIOS") settings either it has nothing to do with whatever you're booting and everything to do with the firmware (UEFI) settings, likely some USB legacy support disabled.

IOMMU's for passing through PCIe and many consumer boards don't support it. Its likely not that.
